# Check if psqlodbc has been unistalled or not from the system

Tags: delphi, postgresql, odbc

Im working on software that required psqlodbc drivers and postgresSQl 9.0 database,
we have a installer designed using delphi 7 to install both psqlodbc and postgreSQl 9 silently
one after the other on click of a single button, here everything runs fine,
but the problem is during uninstall,
i first want to unistall psqlodbc and then postgreSQl 9 also on a sinlge button click,

i want to run the postgreSQl 9 unistaller using shellpApi only after psqlodbc has been unstalled,
as of now im checking for 'cmd.exe' is running or not to start postgreSQl uninstaller, but sometimes after unstalling psqlodbc the 'cmd.exe' remain n the postgreSQl unistaller cannot be executed,

so any please tell me 
how to check if psqlodbc uninstall process is completely.

the files are 
1.psqlodbc.msi
2.postgresql-9.0.2-1-windows.exe

install/uninstall is handled wit bat file

thanks in advanced:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got how to check if psqlodbc has been uninstalled completely so that i can start unistalling postgres

For that i found the solution 
[On stackoverflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443886/delphi-wait-until-bat-script-runs-to-the-end)

```
function TForm1.ExecAndWait(const CommandLine: string) : Boolean;
var
 StartupInfo: Windows.TStartupInfo;        // start-up info passed to process
 ProcessInfo: Windows.TProcessInformation; // info about the process
 ProcessExitCode: Windows.DWord;           // process's exit code
  begin 
    // Set default error result
    Result := False;
  // Initialise startup info structure to 0, and record length
   FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), 0);
   StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
 // Execute application commandline
   if Windows.CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine),
   nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil,
   StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
 begin
   try
    // Now wait for application to complete
     if Windows.WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE)
      = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      // It's completed - get its exit code
      if Windows.GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess,
       ProcessExitCode) then
       // Check exit code is zero => successful completion
      if ProcessExitCode = 0 then
         Result := True;
   finally
  // Tidy up
   Windows.CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
   Windows.CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end;
  end;
 end;
```

so step # 1
    `if  ExecAndWait('msiexec /x  C:\psqlodbc09\psqlodbc.msi')   then
     begin
       //uninstall postgresNow...!!
      end;`

Answer (score 1):

You can check registry if driver is available. When it is installed you will get:

```
c:\tmp\pg>reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\PostgreSQL ANSI"

! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\PostgreSQL ANSI
    APILevel    REG_SZ  1
    ConnectFunctions    REG_SZ  YYN
    Driver      REG_SZ  C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0900\bin\psqlodbc30a.dll
    DriverODBCVer       REG_SZ  03.00
    FileUsage   REG_SZ  0
    Setup       REG_SZ  C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0900\bin\psqlodbc30a.dll
    SQLLevel    REG_SZ  1
    UsageCount  REG_DWORD       0x1
```

And when you unistall it you will get (localized version):

```
c:\tmp\pg>reg query "hklm\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\PostgreSQL ANSI"

Błąd: system nie może odnaleźć określonego klucza rejestru lub wartości.

c:\tmp\pg>
```

(this menas: Error: system cannot find key or value in registry)

See: `reg /?` on how to use it and for return code you can use in batch.

You can also search registry uninstall information under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: hey
Ur idea is good,
but the problem is the registry entry is deleted during the unistall process...
But the unistaller is still running that time,
 what i want is , that how to know if psqlodbc unistall process is fully complete......i m using this batc file to unistall the psqlodbc drivers..."msiexec /x  C:\psqlodbc09\psqlodbc.msi
"

Comment: i edited my question,.....
i can check if  'msiexec' process is running or not, but during uninstall 3 of these 'msiexec' are running but after uninstall One 'msiexec' is still running even though psqlodbc uninstall is complete.!!.....i can also check for 'cmd.exe' but i found in one case that 'cmd.exe' was still running even after unistall

Comment: So you must count `msiexec` processes. On my system ProcessExploer shows full command line of such process: `"C:\WINDOWS\System32\msiexec.exe"  /i "C:\tmp\pg\psqlodbc.msi"` but AFAIK it is not easy to get command line arguments.

Comment: Ok, that also one solution to ckeck for the msiexec count